# How to configure postgresql with flask web app without using ORM?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I want to **configure postgresql with my flask web app**. I don't want to use any ORM. I want to use just simple postgresql
Please guide me with example. I'm new with this technologies.

Comment: https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-part-2-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/  This article help you to configure postgresql with flask

Comment: @Sakeer, I don't want to use any ORM. I just want to simple.

Comment: If you do not want to use any ORM,  please mention that in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use any ORM use the below,

I am assuming you have the basic knowledge of the following:

1. Python — the language.
2. PIP — a package management system to manage and install software packages.
3. Creating virtual environments with Python virtualenv

Create a virtual environment and activate it in your project folder, if you have not already done so.

```
# On Windows
py -3 -m venv venv
source venv/Scripts/activate
# On Linux
$ python3 -m venv venv;
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

### Installing psycopg2

When you think of Python, PostgreSQL and no ORM, psycopg2 will be better. It is the most popular adapter for Python with the core functionality to the Python DB API 2.0. It generally helps you execute your SQL statements and query the database.

With the virtual environment activated, run the following command to install psycopg2 to your environment.

```
pip install psycopg2
```

### Integrating psycopg2 into your python application.

Import it to our python file.

```
import psycopg2
```

### Connecting to a database

.
Before connecting to your database, make sure the following conditions are satisfied:

The postgreSQL server is up and running.
You have a database user created. (You may also use the ‘postgres’ user)
You have set the database password for the user are going to use. You can use the following commands to change the password for the postgres user.

```
\password postgres
```

To change the password for any other user:

```
\password <user_name>
```

Connect to the database. Add the following line to your code:

```
con = psycopg2.connect('dbname='testdb' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='my_password')
```

Replace testdb with your database name.
Replase postgres with the user you will chose.
Replace ‘localhost’ with the IP address of the database, keep it that way if the database is local.
Replace my_password with your user password.
Executing SQL statements
You will need to create a cursor object to execute SQL statements to the database.

```
cur = con.cursor()
```

We are now ready to execute calls. Here is an example to create a simple table.

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test(id serial PRIMARY KEY, name varchar, email varchar)")
```

Here is a simple example to query items from the table and obtain the result as a python object(s).

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
items = cur.fetchall()
```

Finally, after all is done, make the changes persistent to the database by calling the commit function from the connection object.

```
con.commit()
```

Close the database
Once your application has successfully completed it’s need for the database connection, always remember to clean up

```
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: Nice, clear and full answer! (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Just find a postgresql client, here is the best for python + postgresql: http://initd.org/psycopg/